# binding one model with different view models in different user control in same window in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have window which initially gets loaded with a list of item, based on list view item selection, I have to populate data in different user controls in the same window. I have one model which is common across all the user controls but they have separate user controls. Everytime when the data is filled , models gets initialized and data grid remains empty in the UI, even though the data is present at the back end.

```
<Grid >
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="17*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5,5,5.4,5.2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
           <Grid Margin="5">
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 3 0 3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                   <Grid Margin="5">
                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                           <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
                           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="310"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <!--ROW 2-->
                       <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Header="Rule Name" >
                           <ListBox  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                    BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" 
                                    Style="{x:Null}"
                                    Name="lstSuggestedRule" SelectionMode="Single" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding RuleMetadata.SuggestedRuleList, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding RuleMetadata.SelectedRule,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0 3 0 3"  >
                               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                       <Grid>
                                           <TextBlock Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=ExpressionName}">
                                           </TextBlock>
                                       </Grid>
                                   </DataTemplate>
                               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                               <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                                   <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                       <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RuleSuggestionSelectionCommand}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding Path= SelectedItems, ElementName=lstSuggestedRule}" />
                                   </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                               </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                           </ListBox>
                       </GroupBox>
                       <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Rule MetaData"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                           <DockPanel>
                               <local:RuleSuggestionMetaData />
                           </DockPanel>
                       </GroupBox>
                       <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Header="Rule Script" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                           <DockPanel>
                               <local:RuleSuggestionAvalonEditor HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lstSuggestedRule,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource SuggestionVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter= VB}" Margin="0,10,0,10.2" Width="537" />
                           <local:RuleTreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                                   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lstSuggestedRule,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource SuggestionVisibilityConverter} ,ConverterParameter= XML}"  />
                           </DockPanel>
                       </GroupBox>
                       
                   </Grid>
               </Border>

               <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 0 10 3" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  
                   <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Width="100"  
                                   Height="25" Margin="0,3,0,3"
                                   ToolTip="Click to Cancel Operation"
                                  Content="Close" Command="{Binding CancelRuleSuggestion}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" >
                   </Button>
               </Grid>

           </Grid>
       </Border>
   </Grid>

This is the grid structure, where on listbox selection item, I have to populate data into user control ,user control also uses same view model
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Reuse the same view model for multiple controls. Do not make the common error of assigning a private view model to a UserControl, i.e. do not explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext.

Comment: In the main window , I have added the view model as data context and inside the grid in the main window, I have 2 user control which are supposed to load the data from the same model and view model, but in doing so, everytime the user control is loaded, view model and model gets re-initialized hence clearing the data . In doing so, GUI remains empty.

Comment: "*everytime the user control is loaded, view model and model gets re-initialized*" - why does that happen? Please provide the relevant parts of your code.